# Can't understand why the background color of my table is not appearing like I want it to

Tags: javascript, html, node-red

I've recently started using node-red to couple with an OPC UA server.
I want to display a custom template for my dashboard. I'm at the point where I want to change the background color of my table definition. I tried the following:

```
<td ng-style="{'background-color':'{{msg.payload['norm'] == 0 ? 'red' : 'green'}}'}" id="overzicht">Normal {{msg.payload['norm'] == 0 ? 'red' : 'green'}}</td>
```

While the text gets outputted like the following: Normal red, my background color is green which is not what I want.

What can I do to fix this (small) problem?

EDIT:
This is my JS function that returns the msg, I set the msg.payload to an object I've made.

```
msg.topic = "test";
var norm = 0;
var eco = 0;
var empt = 0;
var hyg = 0;
var hygdone = 0
;
if(msg.payload === 0){
    hygdone = 1;
}else{
    hygdone = 0;
}

if(msg.payload === 1){
    norm = 1;
}else{
    norm = 0;
}

if(msg.payload === 2){
    eco = 1;
}else{
    eco = 0;
}

if(msg.payload === 3){
    empt = 1
}else{
    empt = 0;
}

if(msg.payload === 4){
    hyg = 1;
}else{
    hyg = 0
}

obj = {
    "norm":norm,
    "eco":eco,
    "empt":empt,
    "hyg":hyg,
    "hygdone":hygdone
}
msg.payload = obj;

return msg;
```

And here's my HTML template:

```
<div id="table" class="row">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <!-- color="{{((msg.payload['norm'] || 0) % 2 === 0) ? 'green' : 'red'}}"       backup:    {'background-color':(msg.payload['norm'])}-->
            <th id="gray">Overzicht</th>
            <td ng-style="{'background-color':'{{msg.payload['norm'] == 0 ? 'red' : 'green'}}'}" id="overzicht">Normal {{msg.payload['norm'] == 0 ? 'red' : 'green'}}</td>
            <td ng-style="{'background-color':'{{msg.payload['eco'] == 0 ? 'red' : 'green'}}'}" id="overzicht">Energy Save {{msg.payload['eco'] == 0 ? 'red' : 'green'}}</td>
            <td ng-style="{'background-color':'{{msg.payload['hyg'] == 0 ? 'red' : 'green'}}'}" id="overzicht">Hygiëniseren {{msg.payload['hyg'] == 0 ? 'red' : 'green'}}</td>
            <td ng-style="{'background-color':'{{msg.payload['hygdone'] == 0 ? 'red' : 'green'}}'}" id="overzicht">Hygiëniseren Klaar {{msg.payload['hygdone'] == 0 ? 'red' : 'green'}}</td>
            <td ng-style="{'background-color':'{{msg.payload['empt'] == 0 ? 'red' : 'green'}}'}" id="overzicht">Leeg Draaien {{msg.payload['empt'] == 0 ? 'red' : 'green'}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th id="gray">Motoren</th>
            <td id="lightgray">Mixer 1</td>
            <td id="lightgray">Mixer 2 (EC100)</td>
            <td id="lightgray">Ventilator</td>
            <td id="lightgray">0%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th id="gray">Verwarming</th>
            <td id="xlightgray">Product Temperatuur</td>
            <td>0.000 C</td>
            <td id="xlightgray">Mat 1 Temperatuur</td>
            <td>0.000 C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th id="gray">IO</th>
            <td id="xlightgray">Mat 2 Temperatuur</td>
            <td>0.000 C</td>
            <td id="xlightgray">Mat 3 Temperatuur</td>
            <td>0.000 C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th id="gray">Alarmen</th>
            <td id="xlightgray">Verwarmings Matten</td>
            <td id="lightgray">Mat 1</td>
            <td id="lightgray">Mat 2</td>
            <td id="lightgray">Mat 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th id="gray">Diagnostics</th>
            <td id="xlightgray">Programma Keuze</td>
            <td id="lightgray">Kort 0000 Min</td>
            <td id="lightgray">Lang 0000 Min</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th id="gray">Parameters</th>
            <td id="xlightgray">Operationele Stand</td>
            <td>Switch</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't change `'green'` to something else?

Comment: I want the background to be either green or red

Comment: is your td element inside an actual table?

Comment: yes, I have it nested in <tr></tr> tags inside the <table></table> tags

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing the extra `{{}}` inside the `ng-style`? Because as far I know you can already use an expression inside it.

```html
ng-style="{'property': condition ? 'true' : 'false' }"
```

Comment: I'm using the payload from a javascript function as input for my HTML template. I have a variable in my payload which I access like in my code example, if I remove the brackets, It doesn't function anymore

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the inner brackets, like this

```html
<td ng-style="{'background-color' : (msg.payload['norm'] == 0) ? 'red' : 'green'}" id="overzicht">Normal {{(msg.payload['norm'] == 0) ? 'red' : 'green'}}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```html
<td 
  [style.backgroundColor]="msg.payload['norm'] == 0 ? 'red' : 'green'" 
  id="overzicht">
Normal {{msg.payload['norm'] == 0 ? 'red' : 'green'}}
</td>
```

It is always better to address a single style attribute, instead of overwriting the all inline styles.
It is also more readable.

Answer (score 0):

fixed my problem!
Changed my JS function to the following:

```
msg.topic = "test";
var norm = "red";
var eco = "red";
var empt = "red";
var hyg = "red";
var hygdone = "red";
if(msg.payload[0].value === 0){
    hygdone = "green";
}else{
    hygdone = "red";
}

if(msg.payload[0].value === 1){
    norm = "green";
}else{
    norm = "red";
}

if(msg.payload[0].value === 2){
    eco = "green";
}else{
    eco = "red";
}

if(msg.payload[0].value === 3){
    empt = "green";
}else{
    empt = "red";
}

if(msg.payload[0].value === 4){
    hyg = "green";
}else{
    hyg = "red";
}

obj = {
    "norm":norm,
    "eco":eco,
    "empt":empt,
    "hyg":hyg,
    "hygdone":hygdone
}
msg.payload = obj;
return msg;
```

and changed my HTML to the following:

```
<div id="table" class="row">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <!-- color="{{((msg.payload['norm'] || 0) % 2 === 0) ? 'green' : 'red'}}"       backup:    {'background-color':(msg.payload['norm'])}-->
            <th id="gray">Overzicht</th>
            <td ng-style="{'background-color':msg.payload['norm']}" id="overzicht">Normaal {{msg.payload['norm']}}</td>
            <td ng-style="{'background-color':msg.payload['eco']}" id="overzicht">Energy Save {{msg.payload['eco']}}</td>
            <td ng-style="{'background-color':msg.payload['hyg']}" id="overzicht">Hygiëniseren {{msg.payload['hyg']}}</td>
            <td ng-style="{'background-color':msg.payload['hygdone']}" id="overzicht">Hygiëniseren Klaar {{msg.payload['hygdone']}}</td>
            <td ng-style="{'background-color':msg.payload['empt']}" id="overzicht">Leeg Draaien {{msg.payload['empt']}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th id="gray">Motoren</th>
            <td id="lightgray">Mixer 1</td>
            <td id="lightgray">Mixer 2 (EC100)</td>
            <td id="lightgray">Ventilator</td>
            <td id="lightgray">0%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th id="gray">Verwarming</th>
            <td id="xlightgray">Product Temperatuur</td>
            <td>0.000 C</td>
            <td id="xlightgray">Mat 1 Temperatuur</td>
            <td>0.000 C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th id="gray">IO</th>
            <td id="xlightgray">Mat 2 Temperatuur</td>
            <td>0.000 C</td>
            <td id="xlightgray">Mat 3 Temperatuur</td>
            <td>0.000 C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th id="gray">Alarmen</th>
            <td id="xlightgray">Verwarmings Matten</td>
            <td id="lightgray">Mat 1</td>
            <td id="lightgray">Mat 2</td>
            <td id="lightgray">Mat 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th id="gray">Diagnostics</th>
            <td id="xlightgray">Programma Keuze</td>
            <td id="lightgray">Kort 0000 Min</td>
            <td id="lightgray">Lang 0000 Min</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th id="gray">Parameters</th>
            <td id="xlightgray">Operationele Stand</td>
            <td>Switch</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```